# A glitch after Ubuntu Installation. Cannot boot Ubuntu

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I am trying to create a dual boot of Ubuntu 10.10 with Windows 7. My hard disk allocation were as follows:

```
Windows 7  NTFS       100 GB
/boot      EXT4       200 MB
SWAP       LINUX SWAP   4 GB
/          EXT4        46 GB
```

After installation is complete, instead of getting the boot screen of Ubuntu, it directly boots from windows 7 without asking anything.

What is wrong? I run the Live Cd again using USB drive and I see that the \boot, and \ are occupied with most likely Ubuntu data.

Now How do i point my Laptop to point to Ubuntu Boot instead of Windows Boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps below to install GRUB from a live CD it needs to be installed into the Master Boot record of the partition with Ubuntu installed.

[image]

Comment: BTW, give me the source too, I would like to learn more

Answer (score 1):

Where did you install GRUB to? You should be able to recover the installation if you re-install GRUB correctly see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Grub).

I also recommend you read through the Community Documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) - it should give you enough guidance to recover the installation.

Comment: I am not sure... Do you mean, Where I selected the Boot Loader Partition? If yes... I selected the "\" directory

Comment: I thought GRUB would be installed to `\boot` directory. Am I Wrong?

Comment: your /boot partion is not root which is / and any way you should in stall grub to dev/sda the actual root of the drive then update-grub will see all O/S. if you hold right shift key on boot you may see the grub menu in wich case it has a recover menu you can use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for this to happen on a dual-boot system (with Windows wiping out Linux/Ubuntu or vice versa) but recovery can still be a bit touchy.
   If you can get into Ubuntu via the live CD and mount your existing install, you should be able to run `grub-install` and have your boot partitions rediscovered.  A more complete description of options is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Changing%20or%20Moving%20GRUB%202) .  You should at least be able to verify that your Ubuntu install is present.

Here's the relevant community wiki for [Reinstalling from LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD).

Comment: How do i mount my existing Install using Live CD. I am n00b at ubuntu, so please :D dont mind :)

Answer (score 0):

A easy GUI way is to Download [Grub Customizer Portable](http://portablelinuxapps.org/Grub%20Customizer%202.1/download) and then right click properties -> permissions and tick allow excecuting and then run it by double-clicking it and then go to File -> Install to MBR.

Comment: Is this a online package, coz i can't seem to install it. Can you give me the source of that link for more info.