# Blank blue screen after trying to fix plymouth logo

Tags: boot, dual-boot, plymouth

I have ATI Graphics on my machine.

I was trying to fix plymouth logo which was bad looking because of my graphics by following an [article on Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml). Now I cannot login, because I have a blank blue screen.

The drivers had installed flawlessly, once they were detected.

Comment: Which one of these two solutions you used?

Comment: i used the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I would boot using a live cd and go through each step of the article to make sure it matches what you have done on your own machine if everything matches then remove the changes you have made to get back to a working installation.

Hope this helps

Comment: no that does not work, the live cd does not have the programs such as grub.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22866/a-glitch-after-ubuntu-installation-cannot-boot-ubuntu copy grub2 files from live cd

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then...

```
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Delete the line :

```
    uvesafb mode_option=1024x768-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
```

Next...

```
sudo rm /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```